# Route name for url generation when using annotations in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

Let's say I have an action:

```
/**
 * @Route("/current")
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function currentAction() 
{
}
```

And now I need to generate url to this action. `$this->generateUrl()` controller's method accepts route name as an argument. Obviously I have no such name as long as I use annotations.

Any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Got it:

```
/**
 * @Route("/current", name="foobar")
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function currentAction() 
{
}
```

Found it by reading sources, but actually it is explained in documentation as well: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#route-name

As [@Mihai Stancu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/624594/mihai-stancu) mentioned - there is always a default name:

> A route defined with the @Route annotation is given a default name composed of the bundle name, the controller name and the action name.

in this case it will be a `bundlename_controllername_current`

Comment: @leek: for own question you have to wait for 48 hours ;-)

Comment: For the sake of completeness please mention the fact that a name does exist even if you didn't define it. It is constructed as: `bundle_controller_action`.

Comment: @Mihai Stancu: any reference on that?

Comment: In the documentation link that your provided: "A route defined with the @Route annotation is given a default name composed of the bundle name, the controller name and the action name. That would be sensio_blog_post_index for the above example;".